# Overcoming a Very Long JSON String?

Tags: java, android, json, tcp

I am trying to build a weekly schedule, and I want to make an Android app to display it.

I have to send a Week object that contains a list of days, which contains a list of hours, which contains a list of events.

Every event has multiple variables.

The data comes from a local database I built on my PC, and on the app I set a GUI friendly query which returns the planned week in a JSON format.

Now that JSON has become 2000 lines long on the best case, and around 5000 lines worst case.

Any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Another problem is that the JSON comes back in packets, so I cannot parse parts on it until I receive it fully, and Java cannot handle such long strings.

Comment: Hi, I would honestly question why you want to pull the data in this way - why not use a database at the Android side? I am not an expert on this at all, but it seems to me that Firebase is intended for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: As you point out, you have come up with an unwieldy design. However, questions asking for overall design help are not really on topic here.

Comment: @MandyShaw I will go with this suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as your database. Firebase is a cloud database which can be accessed by web and android app also. The data is kept synced at all times so you do not need to fire a different query in your app.

Just store the data in Firebase from your pc and access it via android app and display it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies for not spotting this when I prepared my comment on the question!